# Is there any way to get a thumbsuck idea of how much space your database will need for a search engine?

Tags: solr, nutch

I am creating a crawler that, for arguments sake, will crawl 1 billion pages. I know that is the absolute maximum number of pages I will ever crawl and I know I need to store as much information about each page on the internet. The crawler is [nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) with soir.

How can I reliably decide on the size hard disk I will need to maintain this amount of  data? I can't find any information on how much space a record will take up in [nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/). And I need to know so I can see how realistic is it is to host this on one drive, and if not, what my other options are.

If it takes up 1 kilobyte per page, 1 billion pages will need = 1 000 000 000 / 1024 / 1024 = 95 Terabyte. This is a LOT. But if it is half a byte per page, or pehaps 25% or less off a byte, which would make storing it on only a few servers far more realistic.

Answer (score 2):

You've already done an estimate, but your estimate is probably way off. Almost no modern web page is only 1kb in size (MSN.com is 319KB (58.8KB gzipped) - but 1B web pages is, depending on who you're asking, a measurable amount of the relevant pages on the internet today. And keep in mind, you probably don't just want to store the actual page content, but also index it. This will include several indices, depending on what kind of use you're expecting from the index. Much of the content will probably also be parsed and transformed into other content as well, which will be indexed separately for different usage.

So the only answer possible for such as question is "it depends", and "good luck". Additionally, 95TB is not A LOT of storage today, and could be handled by a single server (storage wise - index usage and query counts will require more servers, but it all depends on what you're going to be using stuff for).

Start somewhere and see where it takes you.

Comment: You answered my question. I need to find a scalable storage solution that will allow for easily spawning across multiple servers when the data becomes more.

Comment: Any suggestions of such a system? :)

Comment: @coderama http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system is a good place to start, evaluating the different options based on your requirements